# How to make the code to jump on any place in the whole code?

Tags: ruby

I AM USING RUBY

```
puts "ENTERING STAGE~1"
puts ""
puts "First_name: "
first_name = gets.chomp
puts ""
puts "You are #{first_name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
true_false = gets.chomp
if true_false == "y"
    puts ""
    puts "Good!"
    puts ""
    puts "ENTERING STAGE~2"
else true_false == "n"
    puts "Please correct the information." #jump: puts "First name: "
end
puts ""
puts "Last name: "
last_name = gets.chomp
puts ""
puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}."
```

I want after "Please correct info..." : the program to jump back on first_name = gets.chomp and further. How to?

Comment: Maybe use a loop.

Comment: I wish more people were this excited about using Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, ruby has no `Goto` statement or anything like that, but you can use recursion and functions to accomplish this:

```
def foo()
    puts "First_name: "
    first_name = gets.chomp
    puts 
    puts "You are #{first_name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
    true_false = gets.chomp
    if true_false == "y"
        puts 
        puts "Good!"
        puts 
        puts "ENTERING STAGE~2"
        first_name
    else true_false == "n"
        puts "Please correct the information." #jump: puts "First name: "
        foo()
    end
end



puts "ENTERING STAGE~1"
puts 
first_name = foo()
puts 
puts "Last name: "
last_name = gets.chomp
puts 
puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}."
```

A similar principle applies for any time you might need the same functionality. You can see that I call `foo()` within itself, that's called **recursion**. With it, you can repeat the same code until the user gets the right input.

Comment: I really think recursion is overcomplicating things here and not good advice to give to a beginner. A loop can do the trick here.

Comment: foo is just a nonsense word that programmers use to demonstrate things.  You could name the function whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for tips to everyone!

Comment: @mikej perhaps you have a point. I am a beginner myself though, and I think learning recursion early on helps in the long run

Comment: Use two spaces for indentation. And `puts ""` has the same effect as `puts`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a looping construct such as a `while`, `until` or `for` loop. A simple example:

```
# We set a boolean value that tells us if our work is done
finished = false

# We use an until loop which will keep repeating until finished is set to true
until finished do
  puts "First name: "
  first_name = gets.chomp
  puts "You are #{first_name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
  response = gets.chomp
  if response == "y"
    # If we receive a y as input, then we can set finished to true to exit the loop
    finished = true
  end
end
```

This code is a little untidy though, and you'd have to repeat it for the second name that follows. Instead consider extracting the read logic into a method.

```
def read_input(prompt_text)
  finished = false
  result = ""

  until finished do
    puts prompt_text
    result = gets.chomp

    puts "You entered: #{result}. Is this correct? [y/n]"
    response = gets.chomp
    if response == "y"
      finished = true
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

You would then call the function like so:

```
first_name = read_input("First name: ")
last_name  = read_input("Last name: ")
puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}"
```

Comment: You had to go and show me up, huh? Accept this one, OP

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents using `loop do`:

```
loop do
  puts "First_name: "
  first_name = gets.chomp
  puts "You are #{first_name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
  true_false = gets.chomp
  break if true_false == "y"
  puts "Please correct the information."
end
puts "Good!"
puts "ENTERING STAGE~2"
```

`break` exits the loop and is executed only if the condition `true_false == "y"` is `true`.
I'd keep the rest outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I would never see the rubyish answer amongst others :)

Comment: **This is the only idiomatic correct answer here so far.**

Comment: OP needs `first_name` later on in the code, here it's lost.

Comment: @SagarPandya Nah, put `first_name = nil` before `loop`, the latter is a closure.

Comment: @mudasobwa My first thought was to assign `loop` to a variable, passing the appropriate variable to `break`. But what you said is pretty neat. TIL...

Comment: @SagarPandya `var = loop { break value } ` is way better and looks more rubyish IMHO.

Comment: @mudasobwa cool. And I see `break` accepts multiple arguments too `a, b, c = loop { break 1, 2, 3 }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop construct. For example

```
true_false = false
while (not true_false)
    puts "First_name: "
    first_name = gets.chomp
    puts ""
    puts "You are #{first_name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
  true_false = gets.chomp
  if true_false == "y"
      puts ""
      puts "Good!"
      puts ""
      puts "ENTERING STAGE~2"
  else true_false == "n"
      puts "Please correct the information." #jump: puts "First name: "
  end
end
```

Comment: Using `while` loop is an anti-pattern in Ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa it will help, if you also could tell, what is not anti-pattern

Comment: An Anti-Pattern, and I quote, is: 

_"A commonly used process, structure, or pattern of action that despite initially appearing to be an appropriate and effective response to a problem, has more bad consequences than good ones."_

Comment: `loop { break if ...; do_stuff }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate for the last name as well you can create a method that gets the name

```
def get_name (type)
  true_false = 'n'
  while true_false != 'y'
    puts "#{type} name: "
    name = gets.chomp
    puts "Your #{type} name is: #{name}. Is info correct? [y/n]"
    true_false = gets.chomp
    if true_false == 'n'
      puts "Please correct the information." 
    end 
  end 
  name
end 

def runner
  puts "ENTERING STAGE~1\n\n"
  first_name = get_name("First")
  puts "\nGood!\n"
  puts "ENTERING STAGE~2\n\n"
  last_name = get_name("Last")
  puts "\nYou are #{first_name} #{last_name}."
end 

runner
```