# How to end the "loop" really the def?

Tags: ruby

I AM USING RUBY

```
def foo()
    puts "First name: "
    first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize
    puts
    puts "Last name: "
    last_name = gets.chomp.capitalize
    puts
    puts "Age: "
    input_age = gets.chomp
    begin
        age = Integer(input_age)
        if age > 0 and age <= 130 then
            puts
            puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}. You have been living for #{input_age} years now. Is entered information correct?  [y/n]"
            true_false = gets.chomp
            if true_false == "y"
                puts
                puts "Good!"
                puts
                puts ".........ENTERING STAGE~2........."
            else true_false == "n"
                puts
                puts "Please correct the information and then proceed to next stage."
                puts
                foo()
            end
        end
    end
end
first_name = foo()
    puts
    last_name = foo()
    puts
    age = foo()
    puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}. You have been living for #{input_age} years now."
```

I am asking how to close "the loop". (really it isnt). Because the program keeps repeating after i answer y (yes, the info is correct).

I HAVE BEFORE THE CODE AND AFTER THE CODE ALSO SOME CODING.

Comment: `(1..130).include?(input_age)`

Comment: Please avoid using capslock. There is no need to yell at people who help you.

Comment: Where is the **loop**? I don't see any. Only recursion.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me again. Use conditional statements to achieve this.

```
puts "Age: "
input_age = gets.chomp
begin
  age = Integer(input_age)
  if age > 0 and age <= 130 then 

    puts ""
    puts "You are #{input_age} yo."

  else
    puts "Put a valid age please."
  end
end
```

And if you want to keep asking until the user inputs a valid age, <s>try using a recursive function</s> Thanks to @dutow for the education, don't use recursion here. Use a loop:

```
def getAge()
  finished = false
  puts "Age: "
  input_age = gets.chomp

  until finished do
    age = Integer(input_age)
    if age > 0 and age <= 130 then 

      puts ""
      puts "You are #{input_age} yo."

      finished = true

    else
      puts "Put a valid age please."

    end
  end
  input_age
end

getAge()
```

***MASSIVE EDIT:***

In the scope of your whole program, here is a working solution:

```
def getName(prompt_text)
  finished = false
  result = ""

  until finished do
    puts prompt_text
    result = gets.chomp

    puts "You entered: #{result}. Is this correct? [y/n]"
    response = gets.chomp
    if response == "y"
      finished = true
    end
  end
  return result
end

def getAge()
  finished = false
  puts "Age: "
  input_age = gets.chomp

  until finished do
    age = Integer(input_age)
    if age > 0 and age <= 130 then 

      puts ""
      puts "You are #{input_age} yo."

      finished = true

    else
      puts "Put a valid age please."

    end
  end
  input_age
end



puts "ENTERING STAGE~1"
puts ""
first_name = getName("First Name: ")
puts 
last_name = getName("Last Name: ")
puts
input_age = getAge()
puts
puts "You are #{first_name} #{last_name}. You have been living for #{input_age} years now."
```

The code you have in your question is ridiculously broken. You have a lot of different things going on, but the moral of the story is: use functions. Use them a lot. They are really useful. Thanks to @Jack Bracken on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540656/how-to-make-the-code-to-jump-on-any-place-in-the-whole-code/51540904#51540904) for some of the updated code.

Comment: But how do i close the "loop"?

Comment: Recursion is a bad idea for this, and similar situations - you should use a loop instead.

Comment: Program then just keeps repeating the def (method?) thing.

Comment: This should only execute once. What is happening when you run it?

Comment: This is in 2 parts. The definition and the call. The section from `def` to `end` is the defintion, and the last line is the call. Whenever you type `getAge()` it will execute the code inside of the function once

Comment: The program asks me if the info is correct i reply y (yes) and it just keeps repeating the def thing.

Comment: @Dutow you may very well be right, but why exactly is recursion a bad idea?

Comment: Is this code you posted part of the last question you asked? if you have the code in a loop of some kind, then it will keep executing.

Comment: Me again. Use two spaces for indentation...

Comment: It is not the loop it is the definition.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the full code, if this is not it? That way we can see if anything is messing with the functionality

Comment: @Cubemaster Recursion is useful when you want to execute the same method, but with different parameters multiple times, usually to calculate something - one of the simplest examples is the factorial, where you keep calling the same method with decreasing values. However it also adds new method calls to the call stack, which means for this increased flexibility, you get increased memory usage, decreasing performance, and a possible stack overflow. Loops are simpler, but faster, and easier to understand.

Comment: @SagarPandya is that better

Comment: @Dutow I have never had to work with a program where that much of a difference in performance was noticible, but that makes a lot of sense for the future. I will fix my answer in a bit, or you can post an answer and get the credit ;)

Comment: Yes. It's a small point but consistent indentation across the community is important.

Comment: @Dutow: The fact that we regularly get absolute newbie questions using tail-recursion to implement repetition instead of loops seems to me to indicate that loops are *not* simpler. In particular, using a loop in this case requires to know about two concepts: methods and loops. Using tail-recursion only requires one concept: methods. The main problem is that Ruby is "broken" in that it leaks memory in tail calls, i.e. it allocates a stack frame even though it doesn't need it. In ECMAScript, Scheme, or Scala, this would *not* exhaust the stack.